# Learning PHP - can someone explain this if statement?

Tags: php

So I'm learning PHP, well I'm learning more complex standards of php as per phpfox.
An issue I'm having is with a few lines of code - I get what they 'do'. But I don't understand why they are structured that way. Could someone explain?

In the following line of code the if statements are cornered by {} and not in the usual:

```
if thing('condition') {
do stuff
}
```

Way that i'm familiar with. Why is this?

```
{if Phpfox::isUser() && !PHPFOX_IS_AJAX && $sCustomViewType === null}
{if (Phpfox::getUserBy('profile_page_id') > 0 && defined('PHPFOX_IS_USER_PROFILE')) 
|| (isset($aFeedCallback.disable_share) && $aFeedCallback.disable_share) 
|| (defined('PHPFOX_IS_USER_PROFILE') && !Phpfox::getService('user.privacy')->hasAccess('' . $aUser.user_id . '', 'feed.share_on_wall'))
|| (defined('PHPFOX_IS_USER_PROFILE') && !Phpfox::getUserParam('profile.can_post_comment_on_profile'))
}

{else}
```

Also what is the :: thing about? and when I see (not in this) a | by itself, what is that doing?

Thanks very much for any help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: My guess is that the kooky PHP syntax could be a templating language of some sort, though I don't recognise it. You should also look at [the scope resolution operator `::`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) and [the bitwise OR operator `|`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Comment: This seems to be a part of a smarty template file and phpfox uses smarty afaik. so that has to be it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like phpfox templates (uses smarty).

http://www.phpfox.com/kb/article/231/template-tags-in-phpfox/

So the part between the {if} and the {else} which you probably left out, is what gets generated (to html) if the condition in the if is true.

The :: thing is the call of a static method. Phpfox is a class with a static method. Those methods do not need a object and are called ClassName::method()

Answer (score 3):

That code does nothing. (Literally, it only checks stuff and does nothing with it).

Don't code that way.

---

As for the `::`, that's called the **[Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)**, it's used to mark static class variables, static class methods and class constants.

The single pipe (`|`) is the **[Bitwise OR Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)**.

Comment: thanks for all the info people :) I'll look into smarty templates as well - I thought the fact that it checked stuff irrelevantly was pointless.

Man stack overflow is so great for learning things. You guys always come through with such great info.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
it seems like this is not exactly PHP only.
it is a part of a smarty template and this is how we use if else in a smarty template file.

example from smarty site itself.

```
{if $name eq 'Fred'}
    Welcome Sir.
{elseif $name eq 'Wilma'}
    Welcome Ma'am.
{else}
    Welcome, whatever you are.
{/if}
```

more details on this link http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if.tpl

DO correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: that seems to be the consensu, i'll look into it - thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You can used if else condition easily in smarty template page .
example from smarty site itself.

{if $name=='anil'}
 anil gupta
{else}
amita gupta
{/if}